# openerp 7 in eclipse with pydev run error

Tags: python, odoo

I was trying to run openerp in order to develop new modules later. I installed indigo and the pydev plugin 2.7.3 then downloaded from launchpad the server/7.0 web and plugin of openerp , have them in a folder then added them to eclipse as pydev project . now when i try to python run the open-server I have the error message`:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/az/openerp_backup/openobject-server-7.0/openerp-server", line 6, in <module>
    openerp.cli.main()
  File "/home/az/openerp_backup/openobject-server-7.0/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 51, in main
    __import__(m)
  File "/home/az/openerp_backup/openobject-server-7.0/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/home/az/openerp_backup/openobject-server-7.0/openerp/addons/web/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cli
  File "/home/az/openerp_backup/openobject-server-7.0/openerp/addons/web/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import test_js
  File "/home/az/openerp_backup/openobject-server-7.0/openerp/addons/web/cli/test_js.py", line 5, in <module>
    import unittest2
ImportError: No module named unittest2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to install an appropriate [python-unittest2](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-unittest2) package with

```
sudo apt-get install python-unittest2
```

Comment: after years, I read our answear, am now a python.odoo expermented developper.
Thanks anyway.